# change objective c to swift code manner

Tags: swift

How to declare this in swift 3:

```
// objective c
static id currentInstance;
```

and then do this

```
// objective c
+ (id)getCurrentViewController {
    return currentInstance;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`static let currenInstance: Any = /*YourClass*/()`

```
static func getCurentViewController() -> Any {
    return /*YourClass*/.currentInstance
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this:

```
class CurrentInstanceHolder {
    private static var currentInstance:Any!

    static func getCurrentInstance() -> Any {
        return currentInstance  
    }
    static func setCurrentInstance(_ instance:Any) {
        currentInstance = instance;
    }
}

CurrentInstanceHolder.setCurrentInstance("aa")

print(CurrentInstanceHolder.getCurrentInstance())
```

Instead of `Any`, you could use `AnyObject` or your specific type. You could also put all the statics into your concrete type.